# Export Sql Server Data To Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Export to Excel is working fine, but if the number has 16 digits it's seen like this:

```
4.26637E+11
```

My Emp_ID:

```
426636773888
```

What can I do to display Emp_ID like this: `426636773888`

.CS Code

```
string strQuery = "select * from Employee;
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd1);

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Employee.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");

    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
    Response.End();
```

See Image
[image]

Comment: You're hit by Excel's ..... desire to try and autoformat the data, more than there's something wrong with the data. Depending on how you're wanting to use the emp_id you might try to export it with a ' in front of it. That'll tell Excel it's a string, and it shouldn't format the code.

Comment: If you're returning the Emp_ID as an INT, you might try a VARCHAR instead. (untested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to export long digits in Excel formula format `="426636773888"` for this field:

```
Response.Write(tab + "=\""+dr[i].ToString()+"\"");
```

Comment: Hiiiiiiii valex Thanks For Ur Reply It's Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with ExcelPackage http://EPPlus.codeplex.com, it will allow you to specify the data type for the column, I used to have the same issues with the date fields.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

Change
    `Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());`

To
    `Response.Write(tab + "'" + dr[i].ToString());`

Just adding a single quote in front of the data, then excel will consider the data as a string.

Comment: Hiiiiiiii Waku Thanks For Ur Reply IT' Working Fine